# How to convert preg_replace to preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, function, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have been working on an old project. During the coding I met with the following function that is throwing error(use preg_replace_callback instead preg_replace). I tried to convert it from preg_replace to preg_replace_callback but getting the error.

Can you please help me in converting the below using preg_replace_callback. Thank you in advance.

```
function deescapeString($s) {

    $torepl = array("/\\\(\d{1,3})/e" => "chr(octdec(\\1))",
                    "/\\\\\(/" => "(",
                    "/\\\\\)/" => ")");

      return preg_replace(array_keys($torepl),$torepl,$s);

}
```